# JavaScript variable updates on its own

Tags: javascript, html, variables, audio, browser

I'm trying to play a sound whenever a number on a homepage updates, depending on whether the number raised or lowered.
Now whenever the specific number updates and I'm trying to compare the old number with the new number, the old number is already updated aswell (see num).

Can anyone help me? :)

```
function beep() {
  var snd = new Audio("url1");
  snd.play();
}

function boop() {
  var snd = new Audio("url2");
  snd.play();
}

var num = 0.0;

document.getElementById('abc').addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  if (document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML != "") {
    var temp = parseFloat($("#abc").text().replace(',', '.'));

    if (temp <= num) {
      beep();
    } else {
      boop();
    }
    num = parseFloat($("#abc").text().replace(',', '.'));
  }
});
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: On its own? No it isn't, you're setting it: `num = parseFloat($("#abc").text().replace(',', '.'));`

Comment: When the number updates on the website the num is already set to the new value at the first if, so it is always the same as temp for some reasson

Comment: `the num is already set to the new value` no, that's not possible with your code

Comment: Then it might be useful to show the code which updates `num`. Variables type of primitive in JS are not updating "on their own", maybe you're trapped by globals?

Comment: there is no other code, only the one i posted

Comment: I think the problem was with the debugger, it seems to work now :) Thanks anyways

Comment: why parse the string again when you have it? Just set num qual to temp `num = temp;`

Comment: `there is no other code, only the one i posted` - then how do you get any boops or beeps at all?

Comment: i removed the urls in the code here for copyright reasons

Comment: if you can, don't use the deprecated DOMSubtreeModified, use a MutationObserver - you probably won't even have to store the old value in that case, because the MutationObserver sends before and after values - your code would look like https://jsfiddle.net/9ozfb3bm/

Comment: Thanks alot :) I'm using the MutationObserver now :)